# How to set interval for aws application load balancer logs in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-aws, logging, amazon-s3

I have successfully enabled logging or my application load balancer and it saves the logs to my s3.
Right now it is saving the logs into

> Amazon >  S3 > xxxxxxxx-logs/ AWSLogs / xxxxxxxxxxxx /
>   elasticloadbalancing / us-west-2 / 2018 / 05 / 30

Last 3 numbers being year / month / day.
So far good. Next day it saves into

> ........ 2018 / 05 / 31

But within the last folder it lists the log entries one by one like this
[image]

I can click on each one and download/open the log. 
How can i configure it so that i receive only 1 file per day? ie. For 2018 / 05 / 31 only one file. There is no configure option such as this in my load balancer. It has only these options
[image]